# Can the heads-up notification height be increased to 256dp?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I see that setting `bigContentView` increases the notification height to `256dp` but this applies to only notification in expanded form.
Can the heads-up notification itself be made of the size of `bigContentView`? Using `headsUpContentView` only increases the heads-up notification size to medium format of 128dp.
 I need large-format version of heads-up `Notification`.

Answer (score 0):

No, *all* notifications will be uniform in height until the user opts to expand them or they are promoted to the top of the notification list.